# Jquery autocomplete select identical menu item when only typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a working autocomplete function on a textbox in my application. If a suggestion is selected the application will post the form to a different page (product category). The user can also type something that is not in the autocomplete suggestions and press enter. In this case the application will perform some textsearch. However...

If the user typed something that exactly matches an autocomplete suggestion and presses enter I still want the application to go to the appropriate url. How can I access the autocomplete suggestions and search for an exact match? I have searched the DOM for an hour (`$(".searchTextBox").autocomplete("instance")`) but could not find anything resembling the 'suggestion set'.

Comment: *"If the user typed something that matches a autocomplete suggestion and presses enter"* - what happens when there are multiple suggestions?

Comment: I meant 'exactly' matches a suggestion. So if someone types 'chair' i want to search the suggestions if there is one that is exactly 'chair'. If so, I want to redirect to the corresponding value of the suggestion. It is not possible that there are multiple exact matching suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by declaring a global (bad I know, but where else?).

```
var autoCompleteResult = {};
```

Then at succes storing a dictionary in the global variable:

```
                success: function (data) {
                    autoCompleteResult = {};
                    var d = data.d;
                    for (var i = 0, len = d.length; i < len; i++) {
                        var val = d[i].split(';');
                        autoCompleteResult[val[0].toLowerCase()] = val[1];
                    }
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split(';')[0],
                            val: item.split(';')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
```

Then, onkeyup on the textbox:

```
    if (autoCompleteResult !== null) {
    if (sender.value !== '') {
        var val = sender.value.toLowerCase();
        if (autoCompleteResult[val])
        {
            setPostBackUrl(autoCompleteResult[val]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm...